# PS Script with POP up for INPUT

Tags: powershell, user-interface

I very new to PS.. I am trying to create a script for an outlook mailbox restore, where I can input the data into a pop up.. for example when I run this script..

New-MailboxRestoreRequest -SourceDatabase "dbname" -**SourceStoreMailbox** "GUID" -**TargetMailbox** "RECDBNAME" -AllowLegacyDNMismatch -**TargetRootFolder** "USERNAME" –name “NAME”

I want the script to pop up asking for the sourcedatabase then the sourcestoreemailbox then targetmailbox then targetroot folder, i've trie with the read-host command don't have any luck.... please help.

Comment: Why not just make it an Advanced Function, and declare those to be mandatory parameters?  Then PS will prompt you for the values if you don't include them in the function call.

Comment: Or if you are on v2.0 or before have the param default to a Read-Host Statement: $myParam = (Read-Host 'Enter some value please')

Answer (score 0):

Just like mjolinor said - make it an advanced function and you'll get the desired functionality. It won't pop-up with a window though in the way PS 2.0 does with Read-Host (perhaps only PS 2.0 ISE did that, can't remember), but will ask the user at run time for input.

For help on advanced functions:

```
Get-Help about_Functions_Advanced
```

Two simple and dumbed down examples (using PowerShell 3.0), demonstrating some differences in behaviour;

```
function Test-Stuff {
Param($TestParameter)
    Write-Output "Testing $TestParameter"
}
```

Output:

> C:\> Test-Stuff
>
> Testing
>
> C:\>

Second example will prompt the user for input when run;

```
function Test-Stuff
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $TestParameter
    )

    Write-Output "Testing $TestParameter"
}
```

Output:

> C:\> Test-Stuff
>
> cmdlet Test-Stuff at command pipeline position 1
>
> Supply values for the following parameters:
>
> TestParameter: This Stuff
>
> Testing This Stuff
>
> C:\>